# Bind DispatcherTimer to Progress Bar XAML WP 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, progress-bar

I'm working in a WP 8.1 application (non SL) and have the following XAML code:

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="TimeBar" IsIndeterminate="False" Maximum="200" Value="30" Height="10" Width="300"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This gives me the following:

[image: progress bar]

I want to bind a timer object, so that as the time ticks and goes forward, the progress bar moves with it, until the timer stops (reaches 1 minute).

I have the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
namespace BarWithTimer
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public DispatcherTimer Timer;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            Timer.Tick += TimerOnTick;
            Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
            Timer.Start();
            NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        private void TimerOnTick(object sender, object o)
        {
            TimeBar.Value += 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your current code works fine to update the progress bar every minute because the interval you have set (1 minute) controls how often the Tick handler gets called.

Comment: Damn, thanks John, I thought I had that on the Seconds, not minutes.

Comment: That said, you probably should use a storyboard instead of a DispatcherTimer, to animate your progress bar smoothly

Comment: How so? do you have any examples please?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jon, all I had to do was fix the interval on the timer.

```
Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50);
```

This now calls the Tick handler every 50 milliseconds, and I can see my progress bar moving!

Thanks Jon.